# How to import many users to firebase auth using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, crud

I want to import 30 users using flutter to firebase, I couldn't find any sources to do so, the only thing I found out was  this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users ,
But I don't no how to implement this in my app

I wanted to store user data in a google docs and convert it into a ".csv" format and upload this from the flutter app to firebase ' Gmail password' authentication

Comment: But i cant use flutter for it, but still thank you

Answer (score 0):

The document you found uses the Firebase CLI. Unfortunately, you can't do this in dart/flutter. But if you want to implement it in flutter you can loop through a list of user objects.

Example:

```
    List list = [{"email":"user1@example.com","Password":"strong password"},{"email":"use2r@example.com","Password":"strong password"},{"email":"user3@example.com","Password":"strong password"}];

    final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    list.forEach((element) async{
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: element.email, password: element.password);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a list of users to the [firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) or your backend service and perform an import like in the document you found.